# how to delete observations from a specific point onwards?

Tags: r, subset, data-manipulation

i have a datased with multiple observations by group. What I struggle to do is to delete all the observations (within each group) from a specific value of a single variable.

For example, considering the dataset below:

```
id  Var1
A  0 
A  0
A  1
A  0
B  0
B  1
B  0 
B  1
```

I want to delete all the observations for A and B after (and including) the first occurence of 1 in Var1; the result would be:

```
id  Var1
A   0 
A   0
B   0
```

any suggestion is very welcome!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the cumulative sum is equal to zero per group.

```
dat[with(dat, ave(Var1, id, FUN = cumsum) == 0), ]
#  id Var1
#1  A    0
#2  A    0
#5  B    0
```

**data**

```
dat <- structure(list(id = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Var1 = c(0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "Var1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .SD[rleid(Var1) == 1], by = id]
```

Output:

```
   id Var1
1:  A    0
2:  A    0
3:  B    0
```

Now this assumes you have no observation starting with 1. Otherwise you could just filter them out:

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[rleid(Var1) == 1 & Var1 != 1], by = id]
```

Otherwise @markus' `cumsum` approach seems to be the most concise, also with `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[cumsum(Var1) == 0], by = id]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `tidyverse`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(row_number() < min(which(Var1 == 1)))  

  id     Var1
  <fct> <int>
1 A         0
2 A         0
3 B         0
```

It is assessing the minimum row number of "Var1" == 1 per groups and then keeps the rows that are below the minimum row number.

Or:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(row_number() <= min(which(Var1 == 0 & lead(Var1) == 1)))
```

It is assessing the minimum row number where "Var1" == 0 and the next "Var1" value is 1 and then keeps the rows that are below or equal to the minimum row number.

Or a `cumsum()` approach already posted by @markus and @arg0naut for `data.table`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 filter(cumsum(Var1) < 1)
```